# Handshake failed in Android Studio app when connecting to localhost

Tags: java, android, sslhandshakeexception

I have the following code in my main Android Studio class:

```
`bgo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("presionado","presionado");

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            Log.e(TAG, "Successfully signed in : " + response.toString());
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error at sign in : " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public HashMap<String, String> getParams() {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("objetivo", "1");
                    return params;
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        }


    }`
```

My intention is to retrieve a JSON String when the button bgo is pressed, however I've never been able to get into the code of the onRespose function because, giving me an error at the onErrorResponse which says:
Error at sign in : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed.

I'm trying to connect to my ipadress:portnumber/folder/index.php with an IP address and port number which this webpage (http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) says is open and available (not blocked from firewall nor incorrect). Also 10.0.2.2:80 is also triggers the error, but not any other url.

Maybe I'm missing somthing in Gradle?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.quetzal.pruebasconexion"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19';
}
```

or the manifest perhaps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.quetzal.pruebasconexion">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".conexion">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I promise I have done extensive research about this in and outside the forum.
May I request your help?

Comment: Hm, you use https but you don't have a valid certificate? If you use port 80, http would be most likely the protocol of your choice.

Comment: I have no words... 4 hours of my life gone (but not wasted, though) for an "s". Thank you so much, it seems like is always 1 letter haunting me c: